# WebDriver - How to read JavaScript response?

Tags: facebook, webdriver, response, share

i am trying to write a test for an Facebook Application. I want to verify a Facebook Share.
So in my code i am able to get the Share Window open. When i Click on Share, i want to get the Javascript Response. In this Response there is the "post_id" which i need to navigate to the published share. How am i able to get this response in Selenium?
The Code to select the shareButton:

```
WebElement shareButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Teilen']"));
```

When i do `shareButton.click` it will do the share. How can i get the response here?

Thx for any help :)

Comment: What is the response you are talking about? Where is it shown? Why do you need it? Where is it stored?

Comment: Hey, here you can see the documentation for the fb.ui feed dialog: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/
This Method have Return Data

post_id :
The ID of the posted story, if the user chose to publish.
I need this data to navigate to the feed entery and check that it was done correctly

Answer (score 0):

From the link you've given it says that when response is received it will populate the `<p id='msg'></p>`:

```
function callback(response) {
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
        }
```

So that means that all you have to do is wait for the element to have something:

```
WebElement myElementWithID = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>(){
    @Override
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
        return d.findElement(By.id("msg")).getText().contains("Post ID: ");
    }});
```

Once that is done just work on the text from the `d.findElement(By.id("msg")).getText().`